# i am not able to make dual boot in asus s56ca

Tags: installation, asus, ultrabook

I am not able to make ubuntu dualboot in my asus s56ca.
i installed ubuntu but then windows not working.

in the boot screen it shows windows 8 but it shows some error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Answer (score 0):

*Windows 8 uses secure boot which makes windows boot-loader unchangable*

so it is not possible to boot other os using windows 8 boot loader. If you have installed Ubuntu using wubi (installing installed windows) then you will fail. You will need to install Ubuntu from a bootable media.

If you have installed Ubuntu by booting from USB/CD/DVD then follow these steps.

1.Restart, press Del, F12 or whatever key that takes you to BIOS settings, once you get into it search and disable secure boot option , save changes and restart.

2.Boot from Ubuntu  USB/DVD into desktop.

3.Open terminal via ctrl+alt+t andtype these commands.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
```

then

```
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
```

finally launch boot repair

```
sudo boot-repair
```

I hope it helps.